# MVC3 - Conditionally add id element with Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I know I can conditionally add an `id` value via

`<select id="@(aBool ? @someId: "")"`

I don't want `id=""`.  This won't pass W3C validation and appears to make jQuery slam its face into the ground.  Can I go a step further and conditionally add `id`?

Something like this (doesn't work):

`<select @(aBool ? id=\"@someId\": "")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just text, so using `@(cond? "id='meep'" : "")` should do it.

As a side note, I finally figured out how you embed expressions in Razor!

Comment: +1 Sure enough, its not as magical as I thought.  `@(cond? "id='" + @meep + "'" : "")` is what I am looking for.

Comment: You don't even need the second `@` in that expression since you're already in an expression. It just reverts back to the C# meaning which does nothing in this case.