# Adding inline conditional statements in an MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to dynamically add a class to a div in an MVC **View**; in this case `error`. I find myself creating a **Razor** `If-Else` block which means my view has lots of duplicated code. I have tried a few differant Razor scenario's but can't find a reasonable way to conditionally append new classes. Can anyone suggest an approach that avoids duplicating code and keeps View decisions in the View.

```
@if (ViewData.ModelState["Title"] != null && ViewData.ModelState["Title"].Errors.Any())
{
    <div class="select error">
        @Html.DropDownListWithTooltipFor(m => m.Title, Model.Titles, new { required = string.Empty, @class = "sel" })
    </div>
}
else
{
    <div class="select">
        @Html.DropDownListWithTooltipFor(m => m.Title, Model.Titles, new { required = string.Empty, @class = "sel" })
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <div @(condition ? "class=select error" : "class = select">
 </div>
```

Razor will add the quotes for you (class = "select error"). This should work in MVC3.
Also, take a look at: [Conditional HTML Attributes using Razor MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061647/conditional-html-attributes-using-razor-mvc3)  and [MVC3 - Conditionally add id element with Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245774/mvc3-conditionally-add-id-element-with-razor) (actually pretty much duplicates)

Note the answer of [Erik Porter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405166/erik-porter): If you can do it with MVC4, then there's a more elegant way:

```
<div class="@yourClass" />
```

Comment: @artur_udod I tried `<div @(ViewData.ModelState["Title"] != null && ViewData.ModelState["Title"].Errors.Any() ? "class=select error" : "class=select") >` but it resulted in `<div class=select error >`. This obviously is wrong... I tried to escape quotes but then it renders the encoded version which is also wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, I got it... this sample works. `<div class="@((ViewData.ModelState["Title"] != null && ViewData.ModelState["Title"].Errors.Any()) ? "select error" : "select")" >`

Comment: <div class="@yourClass" /> is not a more elegant way, the CSS just leaked out of the view and into the controller, no bueno